# Is it possible to keep datetime when performing train_test_split in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

We are developing an Artificial Neural Network, and in that regard, we save X_test, y_test and the predicted values, as a dataframe, and later to a csv file. When we are splitting data with train_test_split, we filter out the datetime, as we are processing data, but we would like to somehow include the datetime later, even after splitting data into training and testing data.

The reason why we would like to include the datetime is that we would like to know the datetime of the processed data, and therefore, it is important for us to have datetime included.

---

Following is the dataframe unprocessed:

```
datetime             temp_20    temp_60    wind_speed    outside_humidity    outside_temp
2015-01-01 13:00:00  22.3       22.1       2.1           70.2                24.5
2015-01-01 14:00:00  22.7       22.2       2.0           71.2                25.2 
2015-01-01 15:00:00  22.9       22.3       2.1           70.8                25.8
...
```

We are splitting values contained in a dataframe with train_test_split in Python:

```
def splitData(dataframe):

    # Separate Target Variable and Predictor Variables
    TargetVariable=['temp_60']
    Predictors=['temp_20', 'wind_speed', 'outside_humidity', 'outside_temp',]

    X = dataframe[Predictors].values
    y = dataframe[TargetVariable].values

    ### Sandardization of data ###
    PredictorScaler = StandardScaler()
    TargetVarScaler = StandardScaler()

    # Storing the fit object for later reference
    PredictorScalerFit = PredictorScaler.fit(X)
    TargetVarScalerFit = TargetVarScaler.fit(y)

    # Generating the standardized values of X and y
    X = PredictorScalerFit.transform(X)
    y = TargetVarScalerFit.transform(y)

    # Split the data into training and testing set
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, PredictorScalerFit, TargetVarScalerFit
```

Following is the ANN:

```
def ANN(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, TargetVarScalerFit, PredictorScalerFit):

    # create ANN model
    model = Sequential()

    # Defining the Input layer and FIRST hidden layer, both are same!
    model.add(Dense(units=8, input_dim=6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

    # Defining the Second layer of the model
    # after the first layer we don't have to specify input_dim as keras configure it automatically
    model.add(Dense(units=6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

    # The output neuron is a single fully connected node
    # Since we will be predicting a single number
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))

    # Compiling the model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

    # Fitting the ANN to the Training set
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=5, epochs=100, verbose=1)

    # Generating Predictions on testing data
    Predictions = model.predict(X_test)

    # Scaling the predicted Price data back to original price scale
    Predictions = TargetVarScalerFit.inverse_transform(Predictions)

    # Scaling the y_test temp_60 data back to original price scale
    y_test_orig = TargetVarScalerFit.inverse_transform(y_test)

    # Scaling the test data back to original scale
    Test_Data = PredictorScalerFit.inverse_transform(X_test)

    TestingData = pd.DataFrame(data=Test_Data, columns=Predictors)
    TestingData['temp_60'] = y_test_orig
    TestingData['Predicted_temp_60'] = Predictions
    TestingData.head()

    # ...
    TestingData = TestingData.round(2)


    TestingData.to_csv("TestingData.csv")

    return TestingData
```

An example of a dataframe (TestingData.csv) with X_test and y_test along with the predicted value 'predicted_temp_60' saved as csv:

```
temp_20    wind_speed    outside_humidity    outside_temp    temp_60    predicted_temp_60
22.3       2.1           70.2                24.5            22.1       21.8
22.7       2.0           71.2                25.2            22.2       22.1
22.9       2.1           70.8                25.8            22.3       22.9
...
```

But we would like datetime to be included in the dataframe as well:

```
datetime              temp_20    wind_speed    outside_humidity    outside_temp    temp_60    predicted_temp_60
2015-03-02 14:00:00    11.1       1.6           87.2                19.5            9.5       9.8
2015-01-24 10:00:00    2.8        3.5           81.8                -1.1            3.9       3.7
2015-12-29 22:00:00    4.3        0.6           72.3                0.2            6.3       6.4
...
```

Comment: I assume the problem is that you don't want datetime to be used as a Predictor, you only want to print it? Maybe `splitData()` could return three dataframes each for train and test, instead of two: `X_train`, `y_train`, and `datetime_train`, with the latter containing the datetime only? Then, when you want to print train, put the datetime back in at the right place in the print statement.

Comment: @joanis That is correctly assumed, but unfortunately I do not think it is that simple. `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)` will split data into training data and testing data, but will not do so in any specific order, and therefore I do not think there is any point in return `datetime_train` as we do not know the order, and therefore cannot put the datetime back to the right place.... Unless, of course I am wrong

Comment: Did you write `train_test_split()` or does it come from outside? I agree, my idea relies on having control over that function too. But maybe you could keep datetime in X before calling `train_test_split()`, splice it out before you feed it to `model.fit` and other functions using it, and insert it back in when you print? I would do that splicing between `train_test_split()` and `return` in `splitData`.

Comment: Is saving `datetime` as an index an option? Then it's just one liner before the functions are invoked and problem solved.
And btw, cheers to DTU ;)

Comment: @joanis `train_test_split()` is a method that we have no control over. It is described here [sklearn train_test_split()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: Then I recommend my second suggestion - give it as input a matrix that includes your datatime column, and splice it out after.